# When I add the name attribute, the form action no longer works

Tags: javascript, php, forms, google-sheets, action

I would like the form, in addition to sending leads to the network with general_api, to save the data on a sheet.
Without writing sheet data, the wf_general_api form action works fine. If I add "name =" on the form, it saves the sheet data correctly but the wf_general_api file no longer works.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" role="form" name="gsheet" action="general_api.php">
```

This is general_api.php for send lead to the network:

```
<?php

function clean_phone_number($value){
  if(substr($value,0,4) == '0039')
      $value = substr($value,4);

  $value = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $value);
  $value = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value);

  if(strlen($value)>10 && substr($value, 0, 2) == '39' && substr($value, 2, 1) == '3')
      $value = substr($value,2);

  return $value;
}

function clean_zipcode($value){

  $value = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $value);
  $value = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value);

  return $value;
}

$post_data = [
  'source_id' => SOURCE_ID,
  'aff_sub1' => '',
  'aff_sub2' => '',
  'name' => $_POST['name'],
  'phone' => clean_phone_number($_POST['phone']),
  'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
  'address' => $_POST['address'],
  'city' => $_POST['city'],
  'zipcode' => clean_zipcode($_POST['zipcode']),
  'notes' => $_POST['notes'],
  'doubleCheck' => 1
];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => SEND_URL,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post_data),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  )
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
$json = json_decode($response,true);

$status = $json['status'];

if($status == 'double')
  $redirection_url = $json['check_url'];
else
  $redirection_url = THANKYOU_URL;

//header('Location: '.$redirection_url);
echo "<script>top.location.href='$redirection_url';</script>";
```

And this is the gsheet for saving data:

```
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxx/exec'
const form = document.forms['gsheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
  })
```

If I add the name attribute, the form action no longer works. If I remove it, it resumes working but does not save the data on the sheet. How can I solve?

Comment: The issue isn't the name, but `e.preventDefault()`. When the javascript works, it submits to Google, but it's preventing the default action. You can leave that line to make sure the fetch works, but then you need to tell it to submit the form afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know where the mistake is, but how can I submit the form afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Once you added the name and the javascript started working, the `e.preventDefault()` prevented the default action for the form. You need to submit the form from within the javascript. I've changed it to the fetch so that it should submit once the fetch is done. Note that this is not tested, but should work:

```
const form = document.forms['gsheet']

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)}).then( () => {
            form.submit();
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work as I would like. Same result as before :(
Saves on sheet but does not allow loading of general_api.php :(

Comment: You might need to check the browser's developer console and watch the network tab to see if it's giving any messages or progress